# Programmatically login to Google Admin Directory in order to create new users

Tags: c#, .net, google-admin-sdk, google-api-dotnet-client, google-signin

I'm trying to convert an older program (.NET C#) so that it works with the new Google Directory API. This program handles the creation of new users taken from a list of users in a database. I can't figure out though how I should go about to programmatically logon to our Google domain so I can start doing things in the Google directory. I have been searching for days on the Internet for a single working example that can take med further. But to no avail. Is there anyone who can shed light on my problem. That would make me very happy. The code I'vecome up with so far is listed below. At the bottom you'll find the error message I get. I know something is missing in the code but I don't know exactly what.

---

```
// Create the service.
var service = new DirectoryService (new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApplicationName = "", 
        ApiKey = "AIzaSy......."
    });

UsersResource.InsertRequest user = service.Users.Insert(new Google.Apis.Admin.Directory.directory_v1.Data.User
{
    PrimaryEmail = "test.testsson@mydomain.se",
    Name = new UserName
    {
        GivenName = "Test",
        FamilyName = "Testsson",
        FullName = "Test Testsson",
    },
   Password = "rtirjm1163278"

});
user.Execute();
```

Console error message:

> ERROR: Google.Apis.Reqeusts.RequestError Login Required [401] Errors [
>   Message[Login Required] Location[Authorization -  header]
>   Reason[required] Domain[global]]

Comment: Thank you Martin for editing my question and tidying up. I wasn't aware of the bold thing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several way to authorise to Google:

1. Simple API access (API keys) as a file, which is a file containing the access credentials that your program read in.
2. Simple API access (API keys) as string(s), which uses strings that you decide on how to use.
3. Authorized API access (OAuth 2.0), which is the descendent of OpenID and makes you authorise to Google via web interface (e.g. Asp.Net).

More information on how to use them [can be read here.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started)

[And here is Google's page for creating them.](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/)